# what motor driver for servo motor?

Tags: driver, servo

In every tutorial I've come across concerning servo motors, no one mentions motor drivers. Instead, they show the servo getting power directly from the microcontroller. Yet, I understand that a lot of current sinks when the torque rises.

So, can I power the servo motor via a power transistor or a motor driver for DC motors, like L293? Or there are any other motor drivers dedicated for servo motors?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**

Even though it was a general question. this is the servo I have in mind: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11884

Answer (score 1):

This is a hobby servo for remote controlled models.  It has got its own motor driver on board, and a closed loop controller.  It's self-contained.  It only requires DC power and the control signal.

### Further reading

- [Hobby servo tutorial](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/hobby-servo-tutorial) written by Sparkfun
- In the industry [servomotor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servomotor) means a motor coupled with a sensor for position feedback.  An industrial servomotor typically requires an external driver and controller.